# В чем разница между `cursor.execute()` и `conn.execute()?` sqlite3

Tags: sqlite3

Делал разные команды с `UPDATE`,`SELECT`,`INSERT` и не понял разницы между cursor и conn. Работают оба одинаково. Объясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в [док](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-connection-shortcut-methods) при вызове Connection.execute() cursor создается неявно.
Немного напрягает "часто излишние", не знаю когда не лишнее.

> ##### Использовать методы быстрого доступа к соединению
>
> Используя методы execute(), executemany() и executescript() класса
> Connection, ваш код может быть написан более лаконично, поскольку вам
> не нужно явно создавать (часто излишние) объекты Cursor. Вместо этого
> объекты Cursor создаются неявно, а эти методы быстрого доступа
> возвращают объекты курсора. Таким образом, вы можете выполнить
> оператор SELECT и выполнить итерацию по нему напрямую, используя
> только один вызов объекта Connection.

```
# СОздать и заполнить.
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("CREATE TABLE lang(name, first_appeared)")
data = [
    ("C++", 1985),
    ("Objective-C", 1984),
]
con.executemany("INSERT INTO lang(name, first_appeared) VALUES(?, ?)", data)

# Вывод выборки
for row in con.execute("SELECT name, first_appeared FROM lang"):
    print(row)

print("I just deleted", con.execute("DELETE FROM lang").rowcount, "rows")

# close() не является методом быстрого доступа и не вызывается автоматически;
# объект соединения должен быть закрыт вручную
con.close()
```

Comment: если у меня весь код БД состоит из conn, работоспособность не изменится? или лучше заменить некоторые функции на cursor?

Comment: Из вышесказанного, думаю что в этом нет необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

cursor.execute() используется для выполнения SQL-запросов через конкретный курсор.

conn.execute() нужен для одиночных запросов через объект соединения.Этот метод создает временный курсор, выполняет запрос и закрывает курсор. Это удобно для одноразовых запросов.

Пример:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

# Используя cursor.execute()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')

# Используя conn.execute()
conn.execute('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition')
```

Использование `cursor` предоставляет дополнительное управление при выполнении SQL-запросов. То есть использование `cursor` обеспечивает более гибкое управление и более широкие возможности в сравнении с `conn.execute()`, что особенно полезно при более сложных сценариях работы с базой данных.

Вот пример:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()

# Выполнение запроса
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')

# Извлечение результатов
result = cursor.fetchall()

# Управление транзакцией
cursor.execute('UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE condition')
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Слышно железный акцент Chat GPT, `более гибкое управление и более широкие возможности в сравнении` масло масленое , разница в чем?